# Can't figure out how to use Flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I admit i'm still a newbie and I just got caught in a storm !

I'm working on a site who's using a **flexslider** on his theme.
My probleme is that i cant figure out how to make it work :(

The developpement environement is Laravel with gulp so i'm sure every plugin is working well my only probleme is how to make it working in the html :

Here is my code :

### HTML :

```
<div id="photos-tab" class="tab-pane fade active in">
   <div class="photo-gallery style1" data-animation="slide" data-sync="#photos-tab .image-carousel">
       <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="flex-viewport">
          <ul style="width: 2600%; transition-duration: 0.6s; transform: translate3d(-5220px, 0px, 0px);" class="slides">
              <li style="width: 870px; float: left; display: block;" aria-hidden="true" class="clone"><img draggable="false" src="htttp://www.placehold.it/950x500" alt=""></li>
                 <li class="" style="width: 870px; float: left; display: block;"><img draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/950x500" alt=""></li>
                 <li class="" style="width: 870px; float: left; display: block;"><img draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/950x500" alt=""></li>
                  <li class="" style="width: 870px; float: left; display: block;"><img draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/950x500" alt=""></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
          <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
             <li><a class="">1</a></li>
             <li><a class="">2</a></li>
             <li><a class="">3</a></li>
             <li><a class="flex-active">4</a></li>
          </ol>
          <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
             <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
             <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="image-carousel style1" data-animation="slide" data-item-width="70" data-item-margin="10" data-sync="#photos-tab .photo-gallery">
       <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="flex-viewport">
          <ul style="width: 2200%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" class="slides">
             <li class="" style="width: 70px; float: left; display: block; height: 70px; position: relative;"><img style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -35px; left: 50%; margin-left: -35px;" draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/70x70#FF0066" alt=""></li>
             <li class="" style="width: 70px; float: left; display: block; height: 70px; position: relative;"><img style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -35px; left: 50%; margin-left: -35px;" draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/70x70" alt=""></li>
             <li class="" style="width: 70px; float: left; display: block; height: 70px; position: relative;"><img style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -35px; left: 50%; margin-left: -35px;" draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/70x70" alt=""></li>
             <li class="" style="width: 70px; float: left; display: block; height: 70px; position: relative;"><img style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -35px; left: 50%; margin-left: -35px;" draggable="false" src="http://www.placehold.it/70x70" alt=""></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
           <li><a class="flex-active">1</a></li>
           <li><a class="">2</a></li>
        </ol>
        <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
           <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
            <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
                            </div>
```

This is what I expect : http://www.soaptheme.net/html/travelo/cruise-detailed.html

One more thing : When I look on the page I'm trying to copie, I see this :

[image: Capture of the page]

But on my screen, the plugin seems not to be launched so I suppose this is the main problem ?

Comment: This looks like the code generated after you instantiated the flexslider plugin, IMO. Plz share your own HTML sources instead + the <script> part where you use flexslider.

Comment: Can you create a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of the issue?

Comment: Not really but I can show you what i want. 
This is what i'm expecting : http://www.soaptheme.net/html/travelo/cruise-detailed.html.
Actually i've just used the html of this website and tried to apply it to my site but obviously i'm not calling the fonction properly and i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Here is the fiddle but he is absolutly not working; must be missing a lot of plugin I'll try to improve it. 
https://jsfiddle.net/zh2Lrvs4/